# Node 14.16.0: Error-Messages after Update

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I've updated Node from version 12.x.x to 14.16.0. After this I get serveral error messages when I try to start the server.
In the package.json I defined under the scripts object a key "start" with value "nodemon server.

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "Hello World",
    "start": "nodemon server"
```

In the Terminal I call `npm start` and get the following error:

> npm ERR! missing script: start

I also tried `node server`. But that isn't successful too. The message is:

> internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883   throw err;   ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module
> 'C:\Users\Marco\Desktop\Studium\UndsoKram\server'
> at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)    at Function.Module._load
> (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
> at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
> at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',   requireStack: [] }

Have someone a idea how too fix that? Is it necessary to go back to node version 12.x.x.?

Comment: Are you sure, you are executing these in the correct directory? Ie, where `package.json` and `server.js` are located? The path `studium\undsokram` sounds like, this is a collection of various projects, and I suspect these projects are located in a subfolder ...

Comment: That's it. I started the server from the wrong directory. Don't know how this happend. I didn't change the path in terminal conscious.